# Set tooltip text to close button of a JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I programmed a `JDialog` to exit with ESC key and I would like to add a tooltip to the exit button that says *"Close with ESC key"*, so that the user knows about it.

Does anybody knows how to achieve it independent to the L&F?

Comment: What do you mean by 'independent to the Look and Feel'?

If you're asking for how to set a tooltip, then you can do that by calling the `setToolTipText(String tt)` method on any JComponent object. Since the JDialog is a JComponent object, you could set the tooltip by that method.

If what you're looking for is different  then please give more details

Comment: If the dialog is decorated, I guess you can't. Or at least with `setToolTipText`. The tool tip of close button in a decorated dialog/frame is given by the OS. https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuK8u.png